# Is there any way to understand if a raw binary firmware is Cortex-M or not?

Tags: assembly, firmware, arm, embedded

I have a list of firmwares, and I should filter just the Cortex-M type. Is there any automated way that I can distinguish them from other ARM firmwares?

I have some ideas like Interrupt vector Table (ivt) or looking for other specific features of Cortex-M like Systick, but I am not sure if they are going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to search for the string `pG` (hex `70 47`, encoded `BX LR`). If you have many of them at even addresses, especially repeated (sequence of empty functions), then it’s a pretty strong hint.

Comment: May I ask why it should work? Is it a special instruction just in Cortex-M firmware? @igor-skochinsky

Comment: It’s Thumb encoding of BX LR and Cortex-M3 uses Thumb-2 instructions. It is, of course, not sufficient indicator alone.